# Simultaneous mongo instances no longer possible?

Tags: mongodb, centos6

I have a production and a development server. The production server is running a mongod and my development server is running 2 instances: 
1 - as "slave" for production (using a replicaSet). This duplicates my data and allows for easier backups. 
2 - a "master". My development collections (couldn't use the slave instance, regarding slaveOkay etc).

They both have their own pid file, data folder, everything. This has been working without much issues for well over a year.

Unfortunately since the last version it seems that whenever I start the one instance, it terminates the other one (prod slave <> dev master). No matter which one gets started first, the other one is always stopped.

Anyone any idea why mongo behaves like this all of a sudden and a solution for the problem? 
Using the master instance to house the development collections is not really an option for me for various reasons.

Hope this makes things a bit more clear:

```
production writes --> production [master] --[replicaSet]--> development instance 1 [slave]
development writes --> development instance 2 [master]
```

Thanks!

Comment: This setup worked and you could write dev data to the dev slave? That sounds...incorrect, anyway what do the logs say

Comment: No it writes on a development master, I've updated the question and hope it's a bit more clear. The logs of the instance shutting down just mention a signal 15 received and then terminate "normally".

Comment: I know of nothing that should effect this setup, what MongoDB version is this? Did you upgrade recently? If so from what version? What has changed recently in your setup?

Comment: yeah me neither... I only upgraded to 2.4.6, nothing else changed. It was probably 2.4.5 before, I keep my machines as up to date as possible. The only weird thing is that my mongod init script has  PIDFILE=`awk -F= '/^dbpath\s=\s/{print $2}' "$CONFIGFILE"` in there. This seems really awkward to me. In my (previously copied) mongod-dev file this is pidfilepath instead of dbpath. I wonder if I changed this accidentally? That would we weird...

Comment: Wait your using an init file to launch these? And you are launching both from the same init file?

Comment: Yes and of course not :) I have 2 different init's and 2 configs (mongod and mongod-dev) and everything has been modified to run separate (pid, log and dbpath). As I already said: this entire setup worked flawlessly for the last year, right up to the upgrade to 2.4.6

Comment: Ah ok ok, hmmm, I know of nothing, I will have to test this myself but I don't actually have a copy of centos6 to hand, only Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for posterity:

It seems the init script for mongo version 2.4.6 has a peculiarity in it. It determines the PID file with the following expression:

```
PIDFILE=`awk -F= '/^dbpath\s=\s/{print $2}' "$CONFIGFILE"`
```

This looks for the dbpath with a whitespace before and after the equal sign.
Since the default config file contains "dbpath=/var/lib/mongo", the result of this expression is empty. 
I imagine the init script - without any specific .pid file being given - just uses the default .pid file location. Normally (with one instance) this has no consequences. In my case it causes the other mongo instance to be terminated.

I've always used the "pidfilepath" config directive up to now (don't recall if this was already in there when I first installed it or not). So basically I've updated my init scripts to (and note the missing "\s"'es)

```
PIDFILE=`awk -F= '/^pidfilepath=/{print $2}' "$CONFIGFILE"`
```

Then I made sure the config statements didn't have spaces:

```
 pidfilepath=/var/run/mongo/mongod-name.pid
```

This solves my problem. I hope it does the same for anyone else in the same situation.

Why use the dbpath for the pid file anyway?

Comment: There is an open issue in the MongoDB issue tracker for this problem with the RPM package: [SERVER-9275](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9275).  Looks like there is an associated pull request with a fix similar to yours, if you want to upvote/watch/comment.